# Trying to project shapefile using to_crs in geopandas gives error

Tags: python, gis, geopandas, map-projections

My data comes from the LA Metro Developer's site. It is a shapefile of stations downloaded from their site:

http://developer.metro.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/RailStations0715.zip

I can load this in a jupyter notebook using geopandas.

```
metro2 = gpd.read_file('data/MetroStations/Stations_All_GCS.shp')
```

Then see a few rows:

```
metro.head()
```

[image]

Check the type:

[image]

Get the projection:

[image]

Then try to project to GCS84 using `to_crs` produces this error:

[image]

Can somebody see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are there any steps in between those you showed?

Comment: Did you rename your file(s), because in the linked zip, there are no Stations_All_GCS.shp files.
Which geopandas version are you using?

Comment: It appears that rebooting my machine helped fix the problem :). Thanks for your comments.